# Understanding めちゃくちゃ and 内容 in this sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, words

I saw this sentence on twitter and kind of cannot wrap my head around its meaning...

> 「男性陣の内容ないのにめちゃくちゃ盛り上がれるの憧れる」

I suppose that **「男性陣」** refers to the males of a certain group; however in connection with **「内容ない」** it seems to me the it means something like "content not directed at the males (of the person's twitter followers)".

I don't understand what is meant by the next part at all. I used to understand **「めちゃくちゃ」** as noun but here it seems to be rather used in an adverbial sense (?).

For me it seemed as if the person wants to express that something not "fitting" the typical "male interested content" is going to be published on the person's twitter; however she is hoping that it will find great appeal anyway.

So how is **「めちゃくちゃ」** to be understood in this sentence?
Is my interpretation of **「男性陣の内容ない」** to me it sounds like as if I am not getting what 「内容」 truly means here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This 男性陣(の) is a subject that corresponds to めちゃくちゃ盛り上がれる, and the の is interchangeable with が. 内容ないのに ("..., although there is no content/substance, ...", "despite emptiness") refers not to 男性陣 but to something non-substantial, such as a superficial announcement/speech, a purposeless party or an idle talk. It may or may not be specified in the previous context.

めちゃくちゃ here is just a slangy adverbial intensifier ("extremely", "insanely", "super"). It safely works as an adverb although a few dictionaries seem to say it's only a na-adjective/noun.

> 男性陣の内容ないのにめちゃくちゃ盛り上がれるの憧れる
>
> - *[if there is no particular previous context]* I envy how guys can get super excited without reasons.
> - *[if there is a concrete "empty" thing in the context, for example]* I envy how the male players can get super excited for this empty announcement.

This may be a sarcasm depending on the context. To say "content targeted at male members", you have to say 男性陣**向けの**内容 or something.